# What does Visual Studio call these tags: <% %>

Tags: c#, visual-studio, symbols

There is an actual name for these tags "<%%>" and I have forgotten what it is.  You use them all the time for setting-up user-control control references or whatever.

**Other uses include things like:**

```
var selector_hidMode = '#<%=hidMode.ClientID %>';
```

But there is a **specific name** for these "operators"

**WHAT ARE THEY CALLED?**

...I have completely forgotten and none of us here remember.

Comment: Angle-bracket-percent-thingies?

Comment: I hate how were unable to google with characters like that. Makes the easiest searches so much harder...

Comment: @PlatinumAzure is it sad that googling angle bracket percent thing actually gets you somewhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Code Render Blocks - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6xeyd4z.aspx

or

Embedded Code Blocks - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: This is the term introduced for them with the advent of ASP.NET Web Pages.

Comment: By the way, I Googled "aspx inline operators" to get this answer.  That is what my brain wanted to call them. From a link on a page in those results I ended up with the two Microsoft pages. The initial link was http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-(3c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc).aspx

Answer (score 4):

[The Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/) calls them [*code nuggets*](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx). I call them *impossible to Google WebForms specific stuff*. But who cares anyway?

Comment: That's a very recent term. :)